# For loop runs twice through everything

Tags: ios, for-loop

I'm trying to add a for loop into my shopping cart so that I can fetch information for specific products which I can then make these information show up in my UITableView.

This is my for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [waren count]; i++) {

        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.someURL.com/%@", [waren objectAtIndex:i]];


        NSLog(@"%@",string);

    }
```

Stuff printed into the log:

```
2013-11-08 10:20:29.885 myClassico[2634:70b] http://www.someURL.com/14549
2013-11-08 10:20:29.886 myClassico[2634:70b] http://www.someURL.com/14565
2013-11-08 10:20:29.886 myClassico[2634:70b] http://www.someURL.com/14483
2013-11-08 10:20:29.886 myClassico[2634:70b] http://www.someURL.com/14549
2013-11-08 10:20:29.887 myClassico[2634:70b] http://www.someURL.com/14565
2013-11-08 10:20:29.887 myClassico[2634:70b] http://www.someURL.com/14483
2013-11-08 10:20:29.887 myClassico[2634:70b] http://www.someURL.com/14549
2013-11-08 10:20:29.888 myClassico[2634:70b] http://www.someURL.com/14565
2013-11-08 10:20:29.888 myClassico[2634:70b] http://www.someURL.com/14483
```

`waren` is a mutable array with is saved in the user defaults. Right now it contains three items but my loop runs through through the array 3 times.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: could you show the actual output?

Comment: Is your code in tableview delegate/datasource method?

Comment: @AshleyMedway done it

Comment: @yen yes it is. Does that effect the loop somehow?

Comment: You are probably calling the method containing your for-loop three times. How do you call your for-loop code?

Comment: It is in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @ConstantinJacob  YES It effect the loop.

Comment: @ConstantinJacob then it's calling the loop for every row

Comment: if you put your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method this method calls 3 times

Comment: oh okay. I understand this. But how do I then get the specific information for each row for the different urls?

Comment: it depends where you calling this for loop.. if you call this for loop inside some table delegate or view handlers! can u add where whole scrip ?

Comment: In ur cellforrowatindexpath just print this : NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.someURL.com/%@", [waren objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]];


        NSLog(@"%@",string);

Comment: [waren objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Comment: Place a breakpoint at the first row, and you'll probably notice that the for-loop is called multiple times.